# copy file from remote server to local server using SSH

Tags: laravel, ssh

i'm trying to download a file using: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/ssh
 but with no success.

my remote.php is ok in config folder, when i run the code below, i get a list of files...

```
\SSH::into('disk')->run(['cd /my/folder/', 'ls',function($line)
{
    echo $line.PHP_EOL;
});
```

but when i run the following code in order to copy a file to my laravel public folder:

```
$test = \SSH::into('disk')->get( '/var/www/html/siged/app.audio/$wav_file', '/var/www/html/siged/public/audios' );
dd($test);// i get null
```

and  file isn't copied to destination folder, can someone help me? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

$wav_file will not be evaluated inside single quotes, try:

`$test = \SSH::into('disk')->get( "/var/www/html/siged/app.audio/$wav_file", '/var/www/html/siged/public/audios' );`

or

`$test = \SSH::into('disk')->get( '/var/www/html/siged/app.audio/'.$wav_file, '/var/www/html/siged/public/audios' );`

...depending on how you prefer your quotes.